# Что использовать для вызова параметра в jsp?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Суть такая:

Добавляю в сервлете аттрибуты, чтоб их передать на jsp страницу

```
req.setAttribute("name", person.getName());
req.setAttribute("surname", person.getSurname());
req.setAttribute("phone", person.getPhone());
req.setAttribute("email", person.getEmail());

req.getRequestDispatcher("/table.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

В jsp странице достаю аттрибуты:

```
<td>${name}</td>    // работает, но кидает варн
<td>${surname}</td>  //работает, но кидает варн
<td>${requestScope.phone}</td>   //работает
<td>${param.email}</td>  // не работает
```

НО

если я из jsp страницы вызываю сервлет:

```
<form action="Controller" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Ivan"><br/>
  Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="Ivanov"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="press me">
</form>
```

а потом из сервлета перехожу на другую jsp передав ему аттрибуты, ТО при попытке достать вот так

```
<td>${param.name}</td>   //работает
```

проблем нет.

Я запутался, в каких случаях использовать ${param.[]}, а в каких ${requestScope.[]}?

Comment: Всё просто. `param` - это map с параметрами http-запроса. Создаётся автоматически. В втором случае у Вас же параметр `name` возникает из `input`-а.  В первом случае очевидно http-запрос не несёт с собой `name`. `req.setAttribute` устанавливает атрибуты, которые доступны на время обработки запроса.